# I have no access to array, but need to remove commas

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

So this is a slightly obscure one.

I'm using Formidable Forms Pro on Wordpress to make quite a complex form. I use a Dynamic Field (who's selections come from entries from another form, hence dynamic) where users can make multiple selections.

I then use a Dynamic List Field to show the users choices more visually.

[image: Dynamic list based on input field]

That image doesn't look too bad, not the best styling but I'm trying to get the mechanics right before making it look pretty.

The styling is in place because I'm hiding commas put in dynamically by Formidable Forms. Herein lies the issue.

This approach would work fine if I wanted the list to appear one on top of the other, but anticipating that users may want to make 10 or more selections in some cases, the list will start to take up too much of the screen.

Now, there are plenty of examples out there of how to remove delimiters from strings and arrays (I believe this is an array of strings,) but, I have no access to either to make the variable to allow that procedure to happen. Leaving it as it is means I can't use CSS Grid to style the list as my hope is to use the repeat auto-fit method to align them all side by side when there's enough space, as the commas are considered a child of the grid element like the list elements.

Inspecting the code shows that there are no html elements encasing the commas so there's no hope to use Javascript there either to remove commas within a class or whatever.

[image: showing commas dynamically injected into code]

If it's possible for anyone with the know how to point me in the right direction it would be gratefully appreciated.

Since I'm using Formidable Forms to create the forms, the only code I can retrieve for you really is the output, which is what I have supplied in the images. Not ideal, I know.

The only pre-rendering code I have access to in Formidable is below. Though I suspect this will be of no use to anyone, which is why I didn't post it originally:

```
<div id="frm_field_[id]_container" class="frm_form_field form-field [required_class][error_class]">
<label for="field_[key]" id="field_[key]_label" class="frm_primary_label">[field_name]
    <span class="frm_required">[required_label]</span>
</label>
<div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_[key]_label" role="group">[input]</div>
[if description]<div class="frm_description" id="frm_desc_field_[key]">[description]</div>[/if description]
[if error]<div class="frm_error" id="frm_error_field_[key]">[error]</div>[/if error]
</div>
```

And the rendered code:

```
<div id="frm_field_70_container" class="frm_form_field form-field  frm_none_container frm_dynamic_data_container">
<label for="field_b0r85" id="field_b0r85_label" class="frm_primary_label">Dynamic
    <span class="frm_required"></span>
</label>
<div class="frm_opt_container" aria-labelledby="field_b0r85_label" role="group" style=""><p class="frm_show_it"></p><div class="combined_field_output"><img src="http://3.11.173.147.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/formidable/2/IMG-20190512-WA0005-29-150x150.jpg" alt="Image of exercise 5545" style="width:60px;height:60px"><h3>5545</h3><p>Abdominals</p></div>, <div class="combined_field_output"><img src="http://3.11.173.147.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/formidable/2/IMG-20190512-WA0005-13-150x150.jpg" alt="Image of exercise goo" style="width:60px;height:60px"><h3>goo</h3><p>Abdominals</p></div>, <div class="combined_field_output"><img src="http://3.11.173.147.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/formidable/2/IMG-20190512-WA0005-27-150x150.jpg" alt="Image of exercise should work" style="width:60px;height:60px"><h3>should work</h3><p>Abdominals</p></div>, <div class="combined_field_output"><img src="http://3.11.173.147.xip.io/wp-content/uploads/formidable/2/IMG-20190512-WA0005-14-150x150.jpg" alt="Image of exercise Walking Lunges" style="width:60px;height:60px"><h3>Walking Lunges</h3><p>Abdominals</p></div><p></p>
```

#### 5545

Abdominals

,

#### goo

Abdominals

,

#### should work

Abdominals

,

#### Walking Lunges

Abdominals

">

**Edit**: Formidable provide a way to [Customise a dynamic link field](https://formidableforms.com/knowledgebase/frm_show_it/#kb-examples)which mentions nothing of the delimiter. It is my understanding that if no delimiter is specified, a comma will be added dynamically, which is what I think is happening in here. Can this PHP hook be edited to specify no delimiter be added at all?

Comment: Please [be civil](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct#unfriendly-language) toward each other. No need for name-calling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have access to javascript post rendering. If you do, you can always use regex to fix your innerHTML

```
var text = document.getElementsByClassName("frm_opt_container")[0].innerHTML;
var reg = new RegExp("(<div class=\"combined_field_output\">.*</div>[.\n\r]*)(,)");
while(reg.test(text)){
  text = text.replace(reg, "$1")
}
document.getElementsByClassName("frm_opt_container")[0].innerHTML = text
```

Comment: If I could take a moment to answer for myself here... @Kelsnare has literaly provided the best answer I could have hoped for. Though I couldn't have written it myself, I can see what he has done. Using regex replace the comma at the end of the div. I'm using css, which I am proficent in, to hide the commas which I can't remove with code. Using CSS to effectively hack the commas from being there visually was not what I was trying to acheive. It was a last resort.
Please either read the post properly, or stop commenting because you're getting it all wrong/out of context.

Comment: @Kelsnare - Thank you for your answer. Formidable provides access for you to add scripts to both before and after form fields. I've tried and it unfortunately hasn't worked.
I've also edited the them to put the script in the footer and ssh'd the theme files back in and that hasn't worked. 
I considered it might have needed to apply to the outer most element to that field so changed ClassName to Id and tried it with the outermost div and that hasn't worked.
I can see what you came up with there and believe it should but it's these quirks that have prevented it so far. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @boxPhresh. my snippet should preferably run after all other scripts by formidable has loaded. The way formidable lets you add scripts may not guarantee them running after all dom modifications by it have been rendered - although I could be very wrong. Try [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) . Maybe you'll get better answers than my hack.

Comment: @Kelsnare thank you. What you've provided makes perfect sence and should work IMHO. I did add the script at the bottom of the page too but to no avail. I think the issue is with how Formidable works.

I've tried to mark your answer as correct but my reputation is too low. When it's improved I'll come back and re-mark it. 

Thanks for taking the time to help.